# Find and proof the exact values to the equations $\sin(\pi/3), \cos(\pi/3), \sin(\pi/6), \cos(\pi/6)$ using $\sin(3x)=3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Find and proof the exact values to the equations $\sin(\pi/3), \cos(\pi/3), \sin(\pi/6), \cos(\pi/6)$ using the proven equality $\sin(3x)=3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$.

---

I figured out $\sin(\pi/3)$ using this quickly. Observe that $\sin(3\cdot\pi/3)=0$, then
\begin{align*}
&0 = 3\sin(\pi/3)-4\sin^3(\pi/3)\\
\Leftrightarrow\,\,\,\, &3\sin(\pi/3)=4\sin^3(\pi/3)\\
\Leftrightarrow\,\,\,\, &3=4\sin^2(\pi/3)\\
\Leftrightarrow\,\,\,\, &\sqrt{3/4}=\sqrt3/2=\sin(\pi/3).
\end{align*}

However I do have some trouble with the rest. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: This is a strange problem. I don't think that equation suffices for all of them (namely, it says nothing about cosine). But if we start dragging in other identities/properties of sine and cosine, I'd just abandon the given equation...

Comment: Why is it important that $\sin(3\cdot\frac{\pi}{3})=0$?

Answer (score 1):

use that $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^2+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^2=1$$
construct a equalleteral triangle with sidelength $a$, then the higt is given by $$4h=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a$$ and $$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a}{a}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If other identities are allowed then
\begin{align}
\sin\left(\frac π3\right) & = \cos\left(\frac π2 - \frac π3\right) \\
& = \cos\left(\frac π6\right) \\
& = {\sqrt 3\over 2} \\
\end{align}
For $\sin\left(\frac π6\right)$we can do
$$\sin\left(3*\frac π6\right)  =1$$
$$3\sin\left(\frac π6\right) - 4\sin^3\left(\frac π6\right)  = 1$$
$$4\sin^3\left(\frac π6\right) - 3\sin\left(\frac π6\right) + 1  = 0$$
$$\left(\sin\frac π6 + 1\right)\left(2\sin\frac π6 - 1\right)\left(2\sin\frac π6 - 1\right)  = 0$$

Since, we know that $$\sin\left(\frac π6\right)\neq -1$$
$$\implies\sin\left(\frac π6\right) = \frac 12$$